# Exam correction is not clear

Tags: grammar-identification

I would like to ask you about 2 questions in the exam that I had (level A1.1), I believe that my answers are correct but my teacher said they are not. Would you please tell me which ones are correct for you and why? Thank you in advance.

1. Welches Kleid gefällt dir ?
   ...... Kleid ist schön.
   Das
   Dieses
   Ein
   Welches
2. Ich habe Halsschmerzen.
   ...... eine Milch mit Honig. Das hilft!
   Trink
   Trinken Sie

My answer for the 1st one is "Dieses" because the answer must point to a specific dress.

My answer for the 2nd is "Trink" because this conversation is not formal and there is no sign for that so no need to use "Trinken Sie".

My teacher considered both answers wrong and said I must choose "Das" and "Trinken Sie". I am not convinced at all.

Comment: You get 100 points from me. Both answers and the explanation are absolutely correct. „Das“ would also be ok, but „dieses“ is even better suited. In the second example, both are possible depending on context. However, I usually don’t advice strangers what to do, so I would also have used the informal „Trink“.

Comment: Thank you so much Axel, your comment makes me happy and feel confident. I had a long discussion with my teacher and she didn't accept my both answers till I showed her the exam correction that "mtwde" posted here. All of you helped me a lot so thank you so much and a special thanks for you because of this boost of confidence 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without further context, you are both right. Both alternatives are possible in each case.

Question 1)
Both "das" and "dieses" would be possible in a conversation. If you had two dresses to choose from, you could point to one and say either "Das Kleid ist schön." or "Dieses Kleid ist schön". Perhaps "dieses" is better in terms of style. (Please note that "Kleid" is always capitalized.)

Question 2)
There is nothing in the question to indicate the relationship between the two people. Correspondingly, one would say "trink" to a friend, or a doctor would say "trinken Sie" to a patient.

**EDIT**

I'm pretty sure [this is the test](https://www.klett-sprachen.de/download/838/Netzwerk_A1-B1_Einstufungstest.pdf) your question is about. In the test, these are questions No. 31 and No. 33.

> 31 -  Welches Kleid gefällt dir? _____ Kleid ist sehr schön.
>
> a) Ein
>
> b) Das
>
> c) Dieses
>
> d) Welches

The given solution in the appendix also included is c = "Dieses". But as I said above, one can discuss whether or not also "b) Das" is correct. However, "das" is a bit more colloquial (and implies an elliptic "da"), so "dieses" may be the better alternative here. But the question "Welches Kleid gefällt dir?" could be answered by "Das da.". So we're in a kind of gray area here.

> 33 - Ich habe Halsschmerzen! _____ eine Milch mit Honig. Das hilft!
>
> a) Trinken
>
> b) Trinkt
>
> c) Trink
>
> d) Trinkst du

The option (Trinken Sie) is not part of the answer options here. Maybe it was a different test, the teacher made a mistake, or you remember wrong. But in this case the only correct answer is also c = "Trink". If another possible answer were "e) Trinken Sie", the question could not be answered unambiguously because, as I said, both (c + e) would be possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but if you have to choose just one answer for each question what would you choose ?  "Das" Kleid doesn't really answer because it doesn't show a specific Kleid right ? Like Which dress do you like ? You must say The red/short/... dress. But since these details/adjectives are absent so you must show a specific dress like pointing to it by your fingers and say This dress. For the second question there is nothing showing it is formal and a doctor would give medical solution as a hint otherwise this conversation is really informal.

Comment: @Myra I've edited my answer and tried to respond to your comment. I think you are right in your thoughts on the first question. In the case of the second question, there is no indication of the relationship (formal or informal) between the two and neither the question nor the answer provide any information about the relationship. That is why this cannot be answered clearly with your possible answers.

Comment: Oh thank you so much for your help and yes I think this is the test, I couldn't remember the other options since I don't have the exam with me. Would you please give me the link of the exam with the answers  please? I really need it to get my marks back, thank you in advance.

Comment: @Myra The file linked in the answer already contains the answers. Scroll all the way down ^^

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that, thank you so much you really helped me a lot. Thank you thank you thank you 

Answer (score 1):

I really think "Dieses Kleid" would be best suited. Just as you have mentioned, it is specific to something.

For the second question, until and unless a context is given, both the options are equally correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and I am sorry for my late reaction, I just saw it. Thank you again 